# CircleCI returns weird error during npm install (no such file or directory...acorn-jsx)

Tags: node.js, npm, circleci, istanbul

Recently I tried to add npm shrinkwrap which result with bunch of errors in CircleCI and most of them I was able to solve but one..

```
npm ERR! argv "/opt/circleci/nodejs/v5.0.0/bin/node" "/opt/circleci/nodejs/v5.0.0/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6
npm ERR! path /home/ubuntu/..../node_modules/eslint/node_modules/espree/node_modules/acorn-jsx
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/ubuntu/.../node_modules/eslint/node_modules/espree/node_modules/acorn-jsx' -> '/home/ubuntu/..../node_modules/acorn-jsx'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

My circle CI file:

```
machine:
  node:
    version: 5.0.0

dependencies:
  override:
    - npm install acorn-js
    - npm install
    - npm install istanbul -g
    - npm install mocha -g
    - npm install karma-mocha -g
```

I had errors with istanbul so i install it globally, and had now errors with acorn-js (which i don't use directly, but i think istanbul is).

Thanks for the help!

Edit:
end up going back to node 4.4.5 and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

So `npm` can't find the file. Have you tried installing `acorn-js` globally as well?

`npm install acorn-js -g`

Comment: Yes, than it asked for another package, and another one. and after 10 packages installed globally i just bailed. I end up going back to node 4.4.5 and removing the specific globally installed package and everything end up fine

Comment: Interesting...so you removed every line except for `node install` under `override`? Or did you just remove `acorn-js`?

Comment: Removed acorn-js, npm install istanbul locally (without -g)

Comment: Cool, good to know (And I meant `npm install` instead of `node install`, sorry about that!).